# iOS app crash, error : unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am having a model which contains key and value. I am passing this value in a swift file as a function parameter. whenever I am trying to run the app in debug mode and I am unable to get a crash. But getting the crash in crashlytics where I am getting the error as:-

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1926611b8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19109855c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x192668268 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x192665270 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x19255e80c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x102be192c (Missing)
6  libswiftCore.dylib             0x102ba0c80 _TFSSCfT12_cocoaStringPs9AnyObject__SS
7  libswiftFoundation.dylib       0x1030a6df8 _TZFE10FoundationSS36_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveCfGSqCSo8NSString_SS
8  Myproject                      0x100520e9c DetailsAndDescriptionCell.configureDetailSection(model : Any, lastIndex : Bool) -> () (DetailsAndDescriptionCell.swift:34)
9  Myproject                      0x1005224b4 @objc DetailsAndDescriptionCell.configureDetailSection(model : Any, lastIndex : Bool) -> ()
10 Myproject                      0x10043d19c -[MyController DetailsInCategories:withTableView:AndIndexPath:] (MyController.m:418)
11 Myproject                      0x10043cb18 -[MyController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (MyController.m:340)
12 UIKit                          0x198859b58 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
13 UIKit                          0x198859d88 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
14 UIKit                          0x198847320 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
15 UIKit                          0x19885edec -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:]
16 UIKit                          0x1985fade8 -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
17 UIKit                          0x198513a80 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
18 QuartzCore                     0x1959c19d8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
19 QuartzCore                     0x1959b64cc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
20 QuartzCore                     0x1959b638c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
21 QuartzCore                     0x1959333e0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
22 QuartzCore                     0x19595aa68 CA::Transaction::commit()
23 QuartzCore                     0x19595b488 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
24 CoreFoundation                 0x19260e0c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
25 CoreFoundation                 0x19260bcf0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
26 CoreFoundation                 0x19260c180 __CFRunLoopRun
27 CoreFoundation                 0x19253a2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
28 GraphicsServices               0x193fee198 GSEventRunModal
29 UIKit                          0x1985817fc -[UIApplication _run]
30 UIKit                          0x19857c534 UIApplicationMain
31 Myproject                      0x10051343c main (AppDelegate.swift:35)
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x19151d5b8 (Missing)
```

This is my model:-

```
@interface KeywordsModel : NSObject
{

}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *key_str;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *value_str;
```

My main question is what does apple mean by **unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC** and how to debug when such error comes in app.

Edit:- I have pasted full crash log

Comment: Show your swift code that uses this

Comment: Also can you paste in the full error from the console

Comment: @sudhanshu, were you able to figure out the meaning of this eror.

Comment: @sudhanshu, did you find any luck on this issue